# Wordpress next_post_link parameters not working correctly

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I'm trying to add a `next_post_link` to a page template but exclude a specific category within a custom taxonomy. I'm able to get the link to work correctly when using the **format** and **link** parameters but it stops loading the link when I add the **in_same_term**, **excluded_terms**, and **taxonomy** parameters.

I've also tried this using the `get_adjacent_post` and `get_next_post` functions but I get the same results. It stops loading the link as soon as I add the **in_same_term** parameter. Anyone have any ideas? Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE, '5', 'mgt_portfolio_filter'); ?>
```

Comment: Same here, but no solution so far :-/